# Error When Setting TextView Text

Tags: android

Please help I'm getting a error when trying to set TextView text to something easy as "Testing".

Here is the error:

> 02-23 21:25:43.610 20928-20928/com.example.edward.datepickertest2
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                           Process: com.example.edward.datepickertest2, PID: 20928
>                                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                               at
>   com.example.edward.datepickertest2.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:28)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: It is clearly saying you are setting value on null(TextView). It is not initialized. so please post your code so we can help you.

Comment: Code here
https://www.dropbox.com/s/446mp92ymwbd0j0/TextView%20Error.txt?dl=0

Comment: post the code here do not share link of ur code..

Comment: Stackflow does not like having code in the comments that is why I made a link to a dropbox shared link and its a note pad file its like 2 kb or something

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button();
    }
    public void button(){
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                textview.setText("Testing One Two Three");
            }
        });
    }

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to initialize the view. First initialize it in onCreate() method using findViewById() then set the value.

Comment: Sorry What? dont understand

Comment: Initialize your textView in onCreate() like...

 TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

and then
myTextView.setText("whatever text you want to set");

Comment: I have. Have you looked at the code that I shared a link to a text document

Comment: its working fine here. I have checked. 
May be you have lots of activity and you're pointing this view to different activity.

Either paste the full code or i can't help without seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

Define id for TextView.
**android:id="@+id/textView"**

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: Since the code its too long for the comments here is a link to dropbox text document.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/56oedqcuvmjk83v/TextView%20Error%20Layout%20Code.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention id to your xml TextView. Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.edward.datepickertest2.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="95dp" />

<TextView
    // missing id 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Well that might be the reason for that. But y did not Android Studio not do that?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException mostly this exception come when you did mention id in xml or initializing findViewById method in java. because i too faced this same problem :)

Comment: Still new to Stackflow how would you do that?

Comment: click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. please check this link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work . accepting answer will encourage us to answer more question.

Answer (score 0):

You posted your xml file, and there is not any id in the `TextView`

```
<TextView
        android:id="textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Without it you can't reference it.